# DiscordAPIError: Missing Perrmissions

Tags: node.js, discord.js

When I'm trying to **ban** someone with **Discord.js**, this error appears:

```
(node:10656) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:10656) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10656) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**With code:**

```
var memberID = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);

memberID.ban();
```

My bot has **all permissions** and I have **two-step verification** on Discord.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Probably that member has a role that is above your bot role in the server settings.

Comment: Is the higest role from the bot higher or lower than the higest role of the member?

Comment: Highest role from the bot is higher than the highest role of the member.

Answer (score 0):

Some more info would be appreciated but besides that,
The higher a role is it has more accessibility.
Pushing your role higher should do the trick, also if you're being rate limited that would be an issue.

[Permission Hierarchy](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions#permission-hierarchy)

[Rate Limits](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#rate-limits)